I can't accest self-hosted supabase with pgadmin
I just deployed self-hosted supabase with coolify on a VPS. Everything is good but I can't acces the database with pgadmin from another server. Am I doing something wrong?
hostname: supabasekong-uwg888k.188.245.53.57.sslip.io
port: 5432
maitenance database: postgres
username: postgress
password: PostgreSQL Password from coolify interface

Here is docker compose file from coolify:
https://pastebin.com/QT5qVJrJ


You'll need to expose port 5432 by adding ports: - '5432:5432' in docker-compose.yml

wonder why the make it publicy options doesnt do that . probably a oversigth. had to do this too . thanks
